# Remove equal objects from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I have the following problem in my ReactJs application. Let's say I have two arrays like this:

```
var cart = [
   {id: 1, name: "item1"}, 
   {id: 2, name: "item2"}, 
];
```

```
var productsArr = [
   {proId: 1, category: 'cat1'}, 
   {proId: 5, category: 'cat7'}, 
];
```

Is it possible to compare these 2 arrays and find any objects in productsArr which cart's `id` quals productsArr's `proId` and remove that object from only productsArr?

(If so, as I explained in this example, `productsArr[0]` should be removed.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, it's possible. Where are you stuck in your code attempt so far?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Array#filter` in conjunction with `Array#some`.

```js
var cart = [
   {id: 1, name: "item1"}, 
   {id: 2, name: "item2"}, 
];
var productsArr = [
   {proId: 1, category: 'cat1'}, 
   {proId: 5, category: 'cat7'}, 
];
productsArr = productsArr.filter(({proId})=>!cart.some(({id})=>proId === id));
console.log(productsArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var cart = [
   {id: 1, name: "item1"}, 
   {id: 2, name: "item2"}, 
];

var productsArr = [
   {proId: 1, category: 'cat1'}, 
   {proId: 5, category: 'cat7'}, 
];


for (var i = 0; i<productsArr.length; i++) {
    if (cart.find(item => item.id === productsArr[i].proId)) {
        productsArr.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}

console.log(productsArr);
```

Comment: Taking into account react.js tag, I would assume, `productsArr` is a part of some component's state, hence immutable approach most likely would be preferred, whereas `Array.prototype.splice()` would mutate original array.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov totally makes sense, I didn't pay attention to the tags

Comment: No worries. You may overcome that, though, by shallow copying initial array, e.g. `const _productsArr = [...productsArr]` and then `_productsArr.splice(i,1)`.